# Filter Hibernate collection : LazyException when all elements are filtered out

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate to load a hierarchical structure where the class HierarchyNode represents any given node in the hierarchy. It simply has the properties 'parent' and 'children'.

In some cases i need to filter children based on one of its properties. Sometimes this results in all child elements for a node to be filtered out. However, it seems that this leads Hibernate to think that the child collection (where all nodes have been filtered out) has not been initialised.

Is there a way to tell Hibernate that even though I'm filtering out all elements for a collection, it should appear as initialised? Right now, I need to use a lot of Hibernate.isInitialised() even in the presentation layer of my application.

Comment: Can you not not set the **lazy** attribute for the collection?

Comment: Problem is that i want to load the entire graph of nodes. That is, nothing at all should be lazy. Hence, I'm fetching all collections when i do the queries, but still when I apply filtering to child collections Hibernate thinks that a collection has not been loaded (and should be lazy) if all elements have been filtered out.